# TypeError: action.payload.filter is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
  import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'


  const reducer = (state, action) =>{

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'IS_LOADING':
        return{
          ...state,
          isLoading: true
        }
      case 'MY_DATA':

          const featureData = action.payload.filter((data)=>{
            return data.rating.rate >= 4.0
          })

          return{
            ...state,
            isLoading: false,
            totalProducts: action.payload,
            featureProducts: featureData
          }

      default: return state
    }
}
const AppContex = createContext()

const API = 'https://fakestoreapi.com/products'
const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  totalProducts: [],
  featureProducts: []
}

const AppProvider = ({children})=>{

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
    
  const fetchData = async ()=>{
    dispatch({type: 'IS_LOADING'})
    try {
      const data = await fetch(API)
      const products = data.json()
      console.log(products)
      dispatch({type: "MY_DATA", payload: products})
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  
    return (
    <AppContex.Provider value={{...state}}>
        {children}
    </AppContex.Provider>
    )
}

const useProductContex = ()=>{
  
    return useContext(AppContex)
}
export {AppProvider, useProductContex, AppContex}
```

i tried to get objects of url which's rating is more than 4 but when there is an error occured in reducer function that action.payload.filter is not a function
i don't understand why is this error occured
in console there is also one error occured which tells that The above error occurred in the AppProvider component:

Answer (score 0):

You should `await data.json()`, see [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
const data = await fetch(API)
const products = await data.json();
```

Answer (score 0):

"filter" is an array method. Check if the payload (i.e,"products") dispatched in the action is an array.

By awaiting data.json(), the products variable will receive the resolved value of the promise, which should be the actual data array.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  dispatch({ type: 'IS_LOADING' });
  try {
    const data = await fetch(API);
    const products = await data.json();
    dispatch({ type: 'MY_DATA', payload: products });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```